# Xstream: overriding default converter

Tags: xstream

I have a list of properties in format:

client.name,
client.zipcode,
client.user.name,
client.user.surname,
client.user.address.street

etc...

I would like to serialize Client.class using xstream but output ONLY fields which are included in this list. I think I should override default ReflectionConverter, but as I see I have to include mapper and reflectionProvider as an arguments to the constructor.

Where can I get these values from? And is this approach correct or maybe I cannot use ReflectionConverter to solve my problem?

Answer (score 2):

You can either configure your XStream object to [omit fields](http://x-stream.github.io/javadoc/com/thoughtworks/xstream/XStream.html#omitField%28java.lang.Class,%20java.lang.String%29) or use the [@XStreamOmitField annotation](http://x-stream.github.io/annotations-tutorial.html).